# Julia convert EnumerableGroupBy to array

Tags: group-by, julia

I have the following code that does a groupby on an array of numbers and returns an array of tuples with the numbers and respective counts:

```
using Query
a = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5]
key_counts = a |> @groupby(_) |> @map g -> (key(g), length(values(g)))
collect(key_counts)
```

Is there a way to complete the last step in the pipeline to convert the key_counts of type `QueryOperators.EnumerableMap{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, QueryOperators.EnumerableIterable{Grouping{Int64, Int64}, QueryOperators.EnumerableGroupBy{Grouping{Int64, Int64}, Int64, Int64, QueryOperators.EnumerableIterable{Int64, Vector{Int64}}, var"#12#17", var"#13#18"}}, var"#15#20"}` to `Vector{Tuple{Int, Int}}` directly by integrating the collect operation to the pipeline as one liner?

Answer (score 1):

**The question has been clarified. My answer is no longer intended as a solution but provides additional information.**

Using `key_counts |> collect` instead of `collect(key_counts)` works on the second line, but `|> collect` at the end of the pipe line does not, which feels like unwanted behavior.

**Below response no longer relevant**

When I run your code I actually do receive a `Vector{Tuple{Int, Int}}` as output.
I'm using Julia v1.6.0 with Query v1.0.0.

```
using Query
a = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5]
key_counts = a |> @groupby(_) |> @map g -> (key(g), length(values(g)))
output = collect(key_counts)
typeof(output) # Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}} (alias for Array{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 1})
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to put the collect operation as part of the pipeline. It does not work for some reason. I will update my question to clarify this. My apologies for a misleading question.

Comment: I see, I also would've thought that `|> collect` at the end of the line would work.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you just want it to be a one liner you can still wrap the piped commands in a `collect()`.

Comment: It may sound silly but I am looking for the pipe working with collect. I believe understanding the technical details will help me in the future.

Comment: It's not silly, I also want to know why piping doesn't work here.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. +1 anyway :-)